Can we use stocktools with highchart core without highstock?
I want to use stocktools with highcharts core, without using highstock in react. Is this possible?
This is what I got from Highcharts GPT:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsStockTools from 'highcharts/modules/stock-tools';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

// Initialize the StockTools module
HighchartsStockTools(Highcharts);

const options = {
  title: {
    text: 'My StockTools Chart'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }],
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};

const StockToolsChart = () => {
  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      constructorType={'stockChart'}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};

export default StockToolsChart;

But it's not working. it's throwing following error:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getAssignedAxis' of 't' as it is undefined.
    at stock-tools.js:10:1
    at e (stock-tools.js:10:1)
    at stock-tools.js:10:1
    at ./src/components/MultiAxis/MultiAxis.jsx (MultiAxis.jsx:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./src/components/ChartsDisplayLayout/ChartsDisplayLayout.jsx (BarChart.jsx:270:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)

Expectation: It should work with highchart core.

Using the stock tools feature (without indicators) with pure Highcharts is possible. You only need to import also the annotationsAdvanced module.
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import annotationsAdvanced from 'highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced.js';
import stockTools from 'highcharts/modules/stock-tools.js';

annotationsAdvanced(Highcharts);
stockTools(Highcharts);


Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ranksh
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/stockTools
Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools
